# Sails.js: Dynamic table name on models

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have made a JS logger application  in Sails.js and everything looks great.
Now, I'm on my way to scale the application: I need to use several tables for the same model (e.g. a table for `session1` `sesson2` etc based on id).

Let's say that for model "Pageview", I'll be using different tables, like "Pageview1", "Pageview2", and so on.

How could I define dynamically the tableName of that model, so I can change it on every request according to a param or attribute.

So far, I have tried this way

```
var tableId = 2;
Pageview.tableName = "pageview" + tableId;
Pageview.create(values, function...);
```

That code does not break the application, or throw any errors, but the record was saved on the default table, instead of the one I wanted.

Comment: What does PageView["tableName"] print? If this prints the default table name then try setting PageView["tableName] = "pageview" + tableId

Comment: Have you tried a string like `var tableId = "two";`?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible to do so , but when i read [**this**](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#custom-format)

I think you can use the custom format to dynamically define table names.

**If you are inserting a row into a table with an auto increment primary key, you can retrieve the insert id like this:**

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', {title: 'test'}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(result.insertId);
});
```

if this is valid for rows , then it might be valid for tables.